# How to get missing dates from a sequence

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have asked one question previously..

[Finding missing dates in a sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36846826/finding-missing-dates-in-a-sequence)

I what I want to find out very first missing date for each ID.

```
ID   DATE
123   7/1/2015
123   6/1/2015
123   5/1/2015
123   4/1/2015
123   9/1/2014
123   8/1/2014
123   7/1/2014
123   6/1/2014
456   11/1/2014
456   10/1/2014
456   9/1/2014
456   8/1/2014
456   5/1/2014
456   4/1/2014
456   3/1/2014
789   9/1/2014
789   8/1/2014
789   7/1/2014
789   6/1/2014
789   5/1/2014
789   4/1/2014
789   3/1/2014
```

Expected results:

```
ID   DATE
123   10/1/2014
456   6/1/2014
```

Comment: Are you assuming that the first entry for each ID is the start of the sequence?  Because `456` and `789` have `3/1/2014`, but `123` starts at `4/1/2014`.

Comment: each Id has different min and max date and I have to find out very first missing date in there related min and max range.

Comment: Is the min and max date in a separate table, or derived from this table?

Comment: I don't get the "put on hold" thing. The question is perfectly clear and I already posted a valid and short answer. It feels as if people who voted to close the question didn't spend much time reflecting about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select cust_id, min(l_dt) as first_missing_date from
   (select cust_id, 
        add_months(lag(dt) over (partition by cust_id order by dt), 1) l_dt, 
        dt 
    from test_data)
where l_dt != dt
group by cust_id;
```

test_data is the name of your table, and the columns are cust_id and dt. (DATE is a reserved word in Oracle, it shouldn't be used for column names.)

This solution uses the analytic function lag(...) - which makes the solution more advanced (a bit harder to follow), but more efficient than using correlated subqueries.

**ADDED** to demonstrate how the query works on my computer (since a comment below states the query gives an error). It works perfectly fine on my machine. I ran this through SQL*Plus, the standard Oracle "DOS-like" interface to the DB. My Oracle version is 11.2.0.2.0 XE (free edition).

```
SQL> select cust_id, min(l_dt) as first_missing_date from
  2     (select cust_id,
  3          add_months(lag(dt) over (partition by cust_id order by dt), 1) l_dt,
  4          dt
  5      from test_data)
  6  where l_dt != dt
  7  group by cust_id;

CUST_ID              FIRST_MIS
-------------------- ---------
123                  01-OCT-14
456                  01-JUN-14
2 rows selected.
Elapsed: 00:00:00.18
```

Comment: This query giving me error, its saying missing expression;

Comment: @Qasim0787 - at which line? What version of Oracle Database do you use? On my computer it works perfectly fine; I will add it at the bottom of my answer to demonstrate.

Comment: It gives error at line #3 showing in ur code. also I am using Toad with Oracle 11.2.0.4.0

Comment: Did you copy and paste the code **exactly** as I posted it? Copy from the web page and paste into Toad? And then changed the table and column names to match yours, exactly? I just did that and it works perfectly fine in Toad. The only thing I can think of is table and column names. Can you compare what you have in line 3 in your Toad version vs. what I posted and see what the differences are?

Comment: yes I exactly copy paste, the key word dt wasn't recognized so, I tried as date as well. I think that is the issue

Comment: Well, of course - I explained in my reply that for MY testing purposes, I called the column dt; in your table it may still be shown as date. If so, you will need to put it in double quotes; don't replace my dt with date, replace it with "date"

Comment: Its working... thanks I got mixed up between l_date and date.

Comment: Thanks you so much

Comment: :-) I had a vague feeling that may be the case (with l_date). Glad it is working.   Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

**EDITED**

```
SELECT ID, ADD_MONTHS(MIN(DATE),1) 
FROM (seelct ID, DATE from yourTable a where
      not exists (select ID from yourTable b
                   where a.ID = b.ID and ADD_MONTHS(a.DATE,1) = b.DATE) )
GROUP BY ID
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 -- every ID has one last month
```

Comment: This will return the last date BEFORE the first missing date, right? In the OP's test data, it will return 9/1/2014 for id=123. The date that must be returned, almost by definition, does NOT exist in the original table. You can fix your solution by wrapping MIN(DATE) within ADD_MONTHS(...).

Comment: Right, i forgot the final goal

Comment: @mathguy: Thanks: that was the 'somthing like'